# Как получить координаты элемента для привязки?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Допустим есть `StackPanel`, в которой содержатся элементы. Допустим, некоторые элементы могут менять свой размер, а значит сдвигать те элементы, которые следуют за ними. Как мне вывести в `TextBlock` текущее положение (координату X или Y в зависимости от ориентации панели) в панели нужного мне элемента? И не просто вывести, а привязать, чтобы я всегда видел положение элемента в текущий момент времени.

Comment: Что вам **на самом деле** надо?

Comment: Вам не должно такого хотеться, и правда.

Comment: @Discord, мне нужно прокинуть стрелочки от одного элемента к другому

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте-ка будем следить за изменениями layout'а:

```
public class LayoutChangeEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public readonly Rect Rect;
    public LayoutChangeEventArgs(Rect rect) { Rect = rect; }
    public LayoutChangeEventArgs(Point loc, Size size) : this(new Rect(loc, size)) {}
}

public class LayoutWatcher : IDisposable
{
    public LayoutWatcher(UIElement target, UIElement origin = null)
    {
        this.target = target;
        this.origin = origin;
        target.LayoutUpdated += OnLayoutUpdate;
        oldRenderSize = target.RenderSize;
        oldRenderPosition = GetRenderPosition();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        target.LayoutUpdated -= OnLayoutUpdate;
    }

    void OnLayoutUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var newRenderSize = target.RenderSize;
        var newRenderPosition = GetRenderPosition();

        var needUpdate = newRenderSize != oldRenderSize ||
                         newRenderPosition != oldRenderPosition;

        oldRenderSize = newRenderSize;
        oldRenderPosition = newRenderPosition;

        if (needUpdate)
            FireChanged();
    }

    UIElement target;
    UIElement origin;
    Size oldRenderSize;
    Point oldRenderPosition;

    Point GetRenderPosition()
    {
        return target.TranslatePoint(new Point(), origin);
    }

    void FireChanged()
    {
        if (Changed != null)
            Changed(target, new LayoutChangeEventArgs(oldRenderPosition, oldRenderSize));
    }

    public event EventHandler<LayoutChangeEventArgs> Changed;
}
```

Тестовая программа:

.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="CoordTracking.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        Name="Root">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Name="Host">
            <Rectangle Name="Target" Width="30" Height="30" Fill="Blue"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1">
            <Run Text="Position: "/>
            <Run Text="{Binding TargetPosition, ElementName=Root}"/>
            <Run Text=", size: "/>
            <Run Text="{Binding TargetSize, ElementName=Root}"/>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        new LayoutWatcher(Target, Host).Changed += (s, args) =>
            {
                TargetPosition = args.Rect.Location;
                TargetSize = args.Rect.Size;
            };
        var dt = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) };
        dt.Tick += (s, args) =>
            Host.Children.Insert(
                    0,
                    new Rectangle()
                    {
                        Width = 20, Height = 20,
                        Fill = Brushes.Aquamarine
                    });
        dt.Start();
    }

    public Point TargetPosition
    {
        get { return (Point)GetValue(TargetPositionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TargetPositionProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetPositionProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("TargetPosition", typeof(Point), typeof(MainWindow));

    public Size TargetSize
    {
        get { return (Size)GetValue(TargetSizeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TargetSizeProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetSizeProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("TargetSize", typeof(Size), typeof(MainWindow));
}
```

Comment: Хороший пример. Спасибо. Думал будет проще.

Comment: @iRumba: У меня как-то была похожая задача, и именно со стрелочками :)

Comment: @iRumba: Не забудьте за-Dispose-ить LayoutWatcher, а то получите утечку памяти.

Comment: @Discord: Там не так просто: изменения могут происходить от любого чиха в layout management'е. Можно подписаться на `LayoutUpdated`, но он случается _чересчур_ часто и даже без реального изменения (что может привести к бесконечным циклам), поэтому мне пришлось отфильтровать.

Comment: @VladD Что там за стрелочки такие, что нужно подписываться на `LayoutUpdated` и вычислять всё вручную?

Comment: @Discord, я был бы признателен, если бы вы предложили способ нанести стрелочки без ручных вычислений

Comment: @Discord: Ну, у вас есть несколько элементов в разных местах UI. Не в одном, общем контейнере. И вам, допустим, нужно соединить их выносной стрелкой, чтобы показать расстояние между ними.

Comment: @VladD Почему просто не подписаться на изменение данных, которые приводят к обновлению координат?

Comment: @Discord: Потому что для этого в этой точке нужно знать их **все**. А это не скалируемо. Например, если поменяется размер окна, то в зависимости от реализации лэйаута может или не может поменяться позиция/размер элемента. Или если у нас много разнородных источников данных «напихивают» свои результаты (разной высоты) в StackPanel, и мы хотим соединить стрелкой какие-то два из них, нам придётся следить за **всеми** промежуточными источниками данных. И это ещё простой сценарий.