# Линия между двумя элементами в WPF

Tags: wpf

Есть тест. Есть варианты ответов которые нужно соединить линией. При том чтобы линия меняла свой размер при изменении расстояния между ответами. Как такое сделать в `WPF`?

[image: Что нужно сделать]

Comment: Хорошо бы, еще приложить к вопросу, несколько слов о том, что Вы уже пытались сделать и что не получилось

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну, это не так сложно технически, но нужно ничего не забыть.

Центральная идея — мы можем выяснить, как расположен один `UIElement` относительно другого при помощи метода [`TranslatePoint`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.translatepoint?view=netframework-4.7.1). А обновления позиции элементов можно получить, подписавшись на [`LayoutUpdated`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.layoutupdated?view=netframework-4.7.1).

Оформим «слежку» за размером вот в такой вспомогательный класс (я украл его [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/451600/10105) и подправил):

```
public class LayoutChangeEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public readonly Rect Rect;
    public LayoutChangeEventArgs(Rect rect) => Rect = rect;
}

public class LayoutWatcher
{
    public void ChangeTarget(UIElement target, UIElement origin = null)
    {
        if (this.target != null)
            this.target.LayoutUpdated -= OnLayoutUpdate;

        this.target = target;
        this.origin = origin;
        OnLayoutUpdate(null, null);

        if (this.target != null)
            target.LayoutUpdated += OnLayoutUpdate;
    }

    void OnLayoutUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var newRenderRect = GetRenderRect();
        if (newRenderRect != currRenderRect)
        {
            currRenderRect = newRenderRect;
            FireChanged();
        }
    }

    UIElement target, origin;
    Rect currRenderRect = Rect.Empty;

    public static Rect ComputeRenderRect(UIElement target, UIElement origin) =>
        new Rect(target.TranslatePoint(new Point(), origin), target.RenderSize);

    Rect GetRenderRect() => ComputeRenderRect(target, origin);

    void FireChanged() =>
        Changed?.Invoke(target, new LayoutChangeEventArgs(currRenderRect));

    public event EventHandler<LayoutChangeEventArgs> Changed;
}
```

Отлично, большой кусок работы готов.

Теперь напишем контрол, который получит в качестве аргументов левый и правый контролы, между которыми нужно провести линию. Он будет наблюдать за изменениями позиции контролов-аргументов, и при её изменении перерисовывать линию.

Поехали! XAML будет очень простым:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.Connector"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Name="ConnectorRoot">
    <Line StrokeThickness="1.5" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=ConnectorRoot}"
          Fill="{Binding Foreground}" Stroke="{Binding Foreground}" x:Name="ConnectingLine"/>
</UserControl>
```

Мы привязали цвет линии к свойству `Foreground` контрола. Вся логика попадает в code behind.

Мы кладём два стандартных `DependencyProperty`, в которых будут элементы, к которым мы привязываемся.

Мы следим за позицией трёх элементов: двух элементов для привязки, и самого себя (ведь нас тоже наш контейнер может переместить!). При изменении элементов для привязки мы меняем и объект слежки.

```
public partial class Connector : UserControl
{
    public Connector()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        selfWatcher.ChangeTarget(this);

        selfWatcher.Changed += RecalcLine;
        fromWatcher.Changed += RecalcLine;
        toWatcher.Changed += RecalcLine;
        RecalcLine(null, null);
    }

    LayoutWatcher selfWatcher = new LayoutWatcher(),
                  fromWatcher = new LayoutWatcher(),
                  toWatcher = new LayoutWatcher();

    #region dp FrameworkElement From
    public FrameworkElement From
    {
        get { return (FrameworkElement)GetValue(FromProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FromProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FromProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("From", typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(Connector),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((o, args) =>
                { var self = (Connector)o; self.fromWatcher.ChangeTarget(self.From); }));
    #endregion

    #region dp FrameworkElement To
    public FrameworkElement To
    {
        get { return (FrameworkElement)GetValue(ToProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ToProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ToProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("To", typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(Connector),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((o, args) =>
                { var self = (Connector)o; self.toWatcher.ChangeTarget(self.To); }));
    #endregion

    void RecalcLine(object sender, LayoutChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (From == null || To == null)
        {
            ConnectingLine.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            return;
        }

        ConnectingLine.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        var fromRect = LayoutWatcher.ComputeRenderRect(From, this);
        var toRect = LayoutWatcher.ComputeRenderRect(To, this);

        ConnectingLine.X1 = fromRect.Right + 5;
        ConnectingLine.Y1 = fromRect.Top + fromRect.Height / 2;

        ConnectingLine.X2 = toRect.Left - 5;
        ConnectingLine.Y2 = toRect.Top + toRect.Height / 2;
    }
}
```

При изменении любой из позиций вызывается `RecalcLine`, который перемещает нашу линию в нужное место.

Теперь пользуемся:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
        Title="Тест" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBlock x:Name="Win10" Text="Windows 10" Background="LightCoral"
                       Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Win8" Text="Windows 8" Background="DarkCyan"
                       Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Win7" Text="Windows 7" Background="Green"
                       Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="WinVista" Text="Windows Vista" Background="Yellow"
                       Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

            <TextBlock x:Name="Y2009" Text="2009" Background="Green"
                       Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="Y2006" Text="2006" Background="Yellow"
                       Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Y2012" Text="2012" Background="DarkCyan"
                       Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Y2015" Text="2015" Background="LightCoral"
                       Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>

        <local:Connector Foreground="Coral"
                         From="{x:Reference Win10}" To="{x:Reference Y2015}"/>
        <local:Connector Foreground="DarkCyan"
                         From="{x:Reference Win8}" To="{x:Reference Y2012}"/>
        <local:Connector Foreground="Green"
                         From="{x:Reference Win7}" To="{x:Reference Y2009}"/>
        <local:Connector Foreground="Yellow"
                         From="{x:Reference WinVista}" To="{x:Reference Y2006}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Получаем:

[image: ух ты, ездят!]